# queries inside and outside a foreach num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to query db to get info, also inside the foreach I need to make some more queries to select and count rows (just checks). I think I can't join queries if I need to count rows...

So I have this:

```
// first query here
$Items = $mysqli->query("SELECT * ...");

foreach ($Items as $i => $ItemInfo) {
    // some checks here before start printing db data
    $a = $mysqli->query("SELECT * ...");
    $num_a = mysqli_num_rows($a);  // 61
    $b = $mysqli->query("SELECT * ...");
    $num_b = mysqli_num_rows($b);  // 63
}
```

I'm getting this:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\views\site\reto.php on line 61

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\views\site\reto.php on line 63
```

I tried some examples from comments in php.net manuals but not working:

```
<?php
    // WORKING CODE:
    $mysqli->multi_query(" Many SQL queries ; "); // OK

    while ($mysqli->next_result()) // flush multi_queries
    {
        if (!$mysqli->more_results()) break;
    }

    $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #1 ; ") // now executed!
    $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #2 ; ") // now executed!
    $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #3 ; ") // now executed!
    $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #4 ; ") // now executed!
?>
```

Maybe I'm doing it wrong:

```
// multi_query here
$Items = $mysqli->multi_query("SELECT * ..."); // doing a normal query???

while ($mysqli->next_result()) // flush multi_queries {
    if (!$mysqli->more_results()) break;
}

foreach ($Items as $i => $ItemInfo) {
    // some checks here before start printing db data
    $a = $mysqli->query("SELECT * ...");
    $num_a = mysqli_num_rows($a);
    $b = $mysqli->query("SELECT * ...");
    $num_b = mysqli_num_rows($b);
}
```

And I'm getting this:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\views\site\reto.php on line 50
```

Maybe I don't need multi_query because I don't need any extra query there...

Anyways, I don't care using prepared statements, probably I'll use them when I get everyting working fine. But the problem is I need the first query (outside the foreach) and I can't close it because I'm printing data in the foreach and I need those checks (row counts) in the foreach also.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Add queries:

```
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}
else {
    $id = get_ip_address();
}

$status_id = 1;  // status message id

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("  (SELECT * FROM user_uploads ORDER by up_time DESC)
                                 UNION
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) rowCount FROM likes WHERE user_id = ? AND status_id = ? AND img_id = ?)
                                 UNION
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) rowCount2 FROM likes WHERE status_id = ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $id, $status_id, $status_id, $img_id);
    $Items = $stmt->execute(); // get photos
}

foreach ($Items as $ItemInfo) {
//how to get the rowCount???
}
```

Comment: You have to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`...

Comment: Nested queries are incredibly inefficient and your code will grow slower and slower; try using JOINs so you can execute a single query to retrieve all your data in one go rather than 10, 100, 1000 separate queries

Comment: Ok, but how I can count the rows in a JOIN query?

Comment: Show your actual queries, and we might be able to answer how to combine them into a single query

Comment: And what is the relationship between the `user_uploads` table and the `likes` table? I guess there's an `id` field in `user_uploads` and a corresponding `id` field in `likes` to define that relationship

Comment: yes ofc: user_uploads.userID and img_likes.user_id (just renamed the table).

Comment: So can a user only have a single upload, or do you want the counts across all uploads by that user?

Comment: No, I'm checking if the user already liked a photo or not, to display Like or Unlike. The page is a list with all photos (from all users) and now I'm scripting the Like/Unlike button.

Comment: Then there needs to be some kind of photo id relationship to the img_likes table, otherwise a user who's liked one image will appear to have liked them all

Comment: Yes, user_uploads.img_id (auto) and img_likes.img_id. That's why I need to query, at least, two times: first to get the images info and second to count the likes and do the checks. The query will be like: "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id = $id AND status_id = $status_id AND img_id = $img_id"

Answer (score 0):

First fetch all your data into an array (http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), then iterate over it.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("Your sql");
$data =  $mysqli->fetchall($query);
foreach ($data as $item) { 
   // more queries here 
}
```

Or even better: Create a join query to fetch all data at once!

reference for how joins work: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

## Example Join Query

For row counts in joins use GROUP BY

```
SELECT m.*, COUNT(s.id) as rowsInSubTable --Where id = same value as mainTable column: sId (see ON) 
FROM mainTable m 
LEFT JOIN subTable s
ON m.sId = s.id
GROUP BY m.id
```

Group By: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Using fetchall it's giving me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\views\site\reto.php on line 47 (foreach line)

Comment: You first need to execute the query and then fetch the data, see new code. you didnt add `;` at the end of every command.

Comment: I would seriously recommend you to use joins, this is easier and better for your performance.

Comment: Ok but then how can I made the row counts?

Comment: see updated answer. you can use the COUNT([column]) to count amount of rows.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that example, but I need something like what I just added up there. Maybe UNION works. But the problem is I need the img_id from the first SELECT so I can do the checks (rowCount)